# How to debug the BSOD with invalid memory reference, specifically, why RSI was set to 0

Tags: windbg

My Windows 10 laptop has been BSODing recently, almost daily, around the time I am not using it (this is a work PC, so the issue happens from like 10pm to 6am). The crash dumps all look the same:

```
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000002d30, memory referenced
Arg2: 00000000000000ff, IRQL
Arg3: 00000000000000e8, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff8011be4e0ff, address which referenced memory
...
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
BUGCHECK_STR:  AV
PROCESS_NAME:  System
...
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8011bf6bba9 to fffff8011bf59dc0
STACK_TEXT:  
fffff801`1dc625c8 fffff801`1bf6bba9 : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00002d30 00000000`000000ff 00000000`000000e8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff801`1dc625d0 fffff801`1bf6855a : 0000006b`b0e5bb5a fffff801`1dc62940 00000000`00000002 fffff801`1bf3aecc : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff801`1dc62710 fffff801`1be4e0ff : 00000000`00000000 fffff801`1bfed7b6 ffffe001`9510d010 ffffe001`97fc14f0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x51a
fffff801`1dc628a0 fffff801`1be4d31b : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc2f
fffff801`1dc62b00 fffff801`1bf5d24c : 00000000`00000000 fffff801`1c126180 fffff801`1c19c740 ffffe001`9355c080 : nt!PoIdle+0x33b
fffff801`1dc62c60 00000000`00000000 : fffff801`1dc63000 fffff801`1dc5d000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x2c

0: kd> .trap fffff801`1dc62710
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000012
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8011be4e0ff rsp=fffff8011dc628a0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up di ng nz na po nc
nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc2f:
fffff801`1be4e0ff 0fb686302d0000  movzx   eax,byte ptr [rsi+2D30h] ds:00000000`00002d30=??
```

And if I am not mistaken, I should look into why RSI was set to 0 before the fault happened. And the "u" command shows a "call qword ptr [rbp+198h]" instruction may have preceded the fault.

```
0: kd> ub rip L13
nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xbe3:
fffff801`1be4e0b3 4032ff          xor     dil,dil
fffff801`1be4e0b6 0fb686302d0000  movzx   eax,byte ptr [rsi+2D30h]
fffff801`1be4e0bd a801            test    al,1
fffff801`1be4e0bf 740f            je      nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc00 (fffff801`1be4e0d0)
fffff801`1be4e0c1 a808            test    al,8
fffff801`1be4e0c3 750b            jne     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc00 (fffff801`1be4e0d0)
fffff801`1be4e0c5 33c0            xor     eax,eax
fffff801`1be4e0c7 b948000000      mov     ecx,48h
fffff801`1be4e0cc 33d2            xor     edx,edx
fffff801`1be4e0ce 0f30            wrmsr
fffff801`1be4e0d0 488b8518030000  mov     rax,qword ptr [rbp+318h]
fffff801`1be4e0d7 458bc4          mov     r8d,r12d
fffff801`1be4e0da 448b8d0c030000  mov     r9d,dword ptr [rbp+30Ch]
fffff801`1be4e0e1 8b54244c        mov     edx,dword ptr [rsp+4Ch]
fffff801`1be4e0e5 488b8c2480000000 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+80h]
fffff801`1be4e0ed 4889442420      mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax
fffff801`1be4e0f2 ff9598010000    call    qword ptr [rbp+198h]
fffff801`1be4e0f8 448be0          mov     r12d,eax
fffff801`1be4e0fb 89442444        mov     dword ptr [rsp+44h],eax
0: kd> u rip
nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc2f:
fffff801`1be4e0ff 0fb686302d0000  movzx   eax,byte ptr [rsi+2D30h]
fffff801`1be4e106 a801            test    al,1
fffff801`1be4e108 7418            je      nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc52 (fffff801`1be4e122)
fffff801`1be4e10a a808            test    al,8
fffff801`1be4e10c 7514            jne     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0xc52 (fffff801`1be4e122)
fffff801`1be4e10e 41b801000000    mov     r8d,1
fffff801`1be4e114 33d2            xor     edx,edx
fffff801`1be4e116 418bc0          mov     eax,r8d
```

Appreciate your guidance as to how to debug this BSOD further. My troubleshooting direction may be false, in which case I am all ears for your insights. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this related to programming? Did you write the affected kernel driver yourself?

Comment: I did not write any code. Instead, my Windows PC has been affected by this BSOD issue. It happens daily, and I would like to find out why it crashed, or at least what I should do to avoid it. The reason I put the question on StackOverflow is that I think there is a better chance that I can get answers here than other places like superusers. I am particularly keen on gaining debugging knowledge with help from seasoned programmers here.

Comment: Given you really find out why it crashed. What would you do next? You can't change the source code, so you can't fix the problem and the answer to the question "what should I do to avoid it" may just be "you can't do anything except reporting it as a bug" or "install a new driver". I still think that this BSOD is an IT issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with some bad software/drivers I installed on this PC. So what I expected out of this debugging is to find out a particular module/application/driver that is causing the issue, then I can uninstall it to try to resolve the issue. Yeah, I agree this is not a programming issue in the sense that I encountered an issue when trying to write a program, but I can't find a debug section on stackoverflow where you can ask debugging related questions, so I posted my question here. If you think there is a better place to submit this kind of questions, please do let me know.